# Display list categories from CTP

Tags: categories

I've create arhcive.php and taxonomy.php as a one template for all my CPT. Now I need to display list of categories (custom taxonomies) but only from current post type. So I have code like this:

```
<?php wp_list_categories( 
    array(
        'show_option_all' => 'wszystkie',
        'taxonomy' => 'drzewa_formowane_categories',
        'style' => 'none',
        'separator' => '',
        )); 
?>
```

Now, how can I modify this code to be "universal"?

---

Ok. I have a little error. Generally this part of code works fine, but when I activate Polylang I see my languages in this list... I have selectet translations for my CPT. Is this possible to specify the range only to CPT taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a taxonomy archive it's fairly straightforward, as you can get the current taxonomy with:

```
$term_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy = $term_object->taxonomy;
```

On a post type archive it's a little bit more complicated as you first need to identify the current post type, and then retrieve the taxonomy/taxonomies attached to that post type:

```
$post_type_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type_object->name );

if ( ! empty( $taxonomies ) ) {
    $taxonomy = $taxonomies[0];
}
```

So you'll need to combine these methods with a check for what you're viewing to get the list of terms in either the current taxonomy or related to the current post type:

```
$taxonomy = null;

if ( is_tax() ) {
    $term_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomy = $term_object->taxonomy;
} elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    $post_type_object = get_queried_object();
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type_object->name );

    $taxonomies = array_filter( $taxonomies, function( $taxonomy_name ) {
        return get_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name )->public;
    } );

    if ( ! empty( $taxonomies ) ) {
        $taxonomy = $taxonomies[0];
    }
}

if ( $taxonomy ) {
    wp_list_categories( array(
        'show_option_all' => 'wszystkie',
        'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
        'style'           => 'none',
        'separator'       => '',
    ) );
}
```

EDIT: I have added this to the post type archive version of the code to filter out any non-public taxonomies attached to the post type:

```
$taxonomies = array_filter( $taxonomies, function( $taxonomy_name ) {
    return get_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name )->public;
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! U r amazing. I decided to create separate archives for each CPT and select CPT taxonomy manually. Is this correct also?

Comment: Whatever's easier for you to maintain. To my mind the less hard-coded stuff the better, and this code will work regardless of the taxonomy or post type.

Comment: I'm wondering now how to do that with 'post_type' when I want query CPT. Is this a similar way?

Comment: When you're on an archive the query gets taken care of for you. What context would you be querying a CPT where this would be related?

Comment: Ok. I will tell you what I want to do. I wand create one universal loop for archive.php for all my CPT. In this loop I wand add this parameters: 
                            'post_status'   => 'publish',
                            'meta_key'      => 'order',
                            'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
                            'order'         => 'asc'

Comment: Sorry for being insistent but I still have a issue with this. I'm using free version of Polylang and when I add your code with this filter thoes taxonomies names are missing. Have you got idea how to make it right? Why am I talking about Polylang: those taxonomies are missing when I turning on translation for CPT. So I think I need to update languages settings for each CPT byt I cant do it with free version...

Comment: You need to take this up with the Polylang developers. The answer is correct for normal WordPress. If you introduce a plugin that modifies standard behaviour you need to sort this out with the plugin developers.

Comment: And... I return to my first block of code and separate archive ant taxonomy templates... :)